# Need to show a graph from Mongodb data

Tags: jquery, json, mongodb, charts

I would like to know what is the best way to do the following.

I store data of what a person has done in Mongodb like a log

e.g.

```
{
 "date":"01-01-2002T08:20:30",
 "task":"contact-lead",
 "user":"username"
}
```

What I need is to count how many tasks where done in that day and put them in a [graph like Highstock](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command bellow will aggregate/count the number of tasks per day:

```
db.col.group({
    $keyf : function(doc) {
        return { "day" : doc.date.getFullYear() + "/" + (doc.date.getMonth()+1) + "/" + doc.date.getDate() };
    },
    initial: {count:0},
    reduce: function(obj, prev) { prev.count++; }
})
```

Then you just format them if needed and send it to highcharts API, but be careful because if you have a lot of data that can be slow.

The other option is to use [MapReduce](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce) and periodically update the aggregate collection and use that as a source for your graphs.

Answer (score 0):

1. use a server side script like PHP or Python to aggregate your data using mongodb queries.
2. [count()](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%7B%7Bcount%28%29%7D%7D) , $where , [$gte ,$gt](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%3C,%3C=,%3E,%3E=) will be the operators you can use to query total number of tasks done on day x .
3. If you need to find number of tasks done on say last  30 days, it would not be a good idea to execute 30 queries, than you would have to use a 'group by' sql equivalent for mongodb, that technique is called '[map reduce](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation#Aggregation-Group)'.

Then you can render your chart data in json/xml format using PHP/Python on the webpage, as required by your charting library Highcharts (or you can also try [jqplot.com](http://www.jqplot.com/) for jQuery based charting).